# Constraints or bindings in Adobe Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Is it possible to add any bindings between object dimensions and positions in Adobe Illustrator?

For example, I have 3 rectangles. One of them has size W x H, second - (W + 10) x (H + 10), third (W + 20) x (H + 20). If one is resized other rectangles should be adjusted. Is it possible to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible doing that in Illustrator by using Symbols.

1. Draw your W x H rectangle
2. Drag it into the symbols plane, now your rectangle is now a symbol
3. drop the new symbol that you already have made in your artboard.
4. scale the new dropped symbol into W+10 x H+10 and repeat this step of the third rectangle W+20 x H+20.
5. Now every time you want to adjust the three rectangles in same time just double click on the first symbol you create it and adjust it you will note that the other rectangles will adjust themselves accordingly.

Comment: This is not working. Also, I cant change color of the rectangles when they created using Symbols.

Comment: For the colors, you may change each instant of the main symbol by using the appearance panel. just select the instant symbol and add a fill color in the appearance panel. and For the steps I mentioned in my answer sure it is working unless you miss a step, or I miss understand what is your needs exactly.

Comment: Step 5 is not working.

Comment: when you created a symbol the rectangle becomes now a shape inside the symbol ... so when you want to edit that rectangle you should go inside that symbol and reshape it .. this would be done by double clicking over the symbol (any symbol by the way) in your artboard or just double click it in the symbols panel.